VSCode unable to resolve absolute paths in angular project
So I have a repository which has the code for both Angular app and Nestjs app. Folder structure looks like:
|server
----|main.ts
----|other server files...
|src
----|index.html
----|main.ts
----|other angular components
|tsconfig.app.json
|tsconfig.build.json
|package.json

My tsconfig.app.json looks like (which is being used for compiling angular app):
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "module": "ES2022",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["ES2022", "dom"],
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "@angular/language-service"
      }
    ]
  },
  "files": ["src/main.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "server", "e2e"]
}


I have a code inside src folder, where I want to access some interfaces from server folder. I try to import using import { UserRecord } from 'server/users/interfaces/user'; But it is giving me the error: Cannot find module 'server/users/interfaces/user' or its corresponding type declarations.
Similarly I try to access the files within the same src folder like import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';, it gives me the same error.
The relative paths works fine but absolute paths not working. Please help.

In Angular you have to defined your absolute paths.
The best practice would be to export what you need from a project in a index.ts file located within the project (usually src directory):
index.ts
import * from './server/users/interfaces/user'

of course what are you trying to access from this import should have the key "export"
And then make this file available from the main tsconfig.json:
...
"paths": {
    "@server": [
        "server/src/index.ts"
    ],
}
...

And then in your Angular application you will be able to import elements declared in the server index.ts:
import { UserRecord } from '@server/user';


appreciate your quick answer. Is there any quick workaround for this? I can do this but I have hundreds of file so it would take days to check and add required files in index.ts?

Can you share also what's inside server/users/interfaces/user file?

Hey, my problem gets fixed if I add this line "include": ["src/**/*.ts"] in the tsconfig.ts file. However, the ng build fails after adding this and gives a lot of errors for components. Any suggestions on this?
